# What does Tile based rendering mean?

Tags: webgl, figma

[tile based](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KN6RL.jpg)

I am wondering what ‘tile based’ here means about figma.
Any one got any paper or ideas.

Thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide your canvas up into a grid. Each square on that grid is a tile. This renderer would render each of those tiles individually, then save the resulting image somewhere. Each of these images are then drawn onto the grid at the spot where they are supposed to go.

It allows The renderer to cache each tile, so it only needs to render tiles that just came into view. Or if something in one tile changes, you only need to re-render that one tile and not the entire screen.

Comment: Thanks a huge! Is there any paper or blog with any detailed examples I can find?

Comment: Nothing a quick web search can't get you, no.